# Multiple Devise roles sharing one base table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a system with Rails 4 and Devise. My goal is to have one User base model and then allowing each User to be either a Client, a Seller or both, this way a client email cannot be used by a seller, but a client can also become a seller, for instance.

I have a basic User model and, based on an attribute called **create_as** I create the dependent table. I set this up using two **has_one** relations for the time being:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :seller, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :client, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :create_client_or_seller

  attr_accessor :phone_number
  attr_accessor :create_as

  protected

  def create_client_or_seller
    if create_as == 'client'
      self.client = Client.create(phone_number: phone_number)
    elsif create_as == 'seller'
      self.seller = Seller.create
    end
  end
end
```

My problem right now is that the Client, for instance, has a PIN number that is automatically generated by an **after_create** hook in the Client model.

I wanted to send this PIN number as part of the email that Devise sends to confirm the email address, but I found out that it is sent before the User **after_create** hook (create_client_or_seller) is called.

I thought about using STI, but it may not be the best approach, given that I have different specialized fields for each "role".

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you use STI or not I don't know if solve the problem :), I prefer to use 2 different models (with devise) instead of using STI since for the STI you will need to create two other class, fields, etc.

I don't know how do you generate the ping but maybe you should change the callback to (for example) before_create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change to before_create hooks.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_create :build_client_or_seller

  protected

  def build_client_or_seller
    if create_as == 'client'
      self.client.build(phone_number: phone_number)
    elsif create_as == 'seller'
      self.seller.build
    end
  end
end
```

Set the PIN in a before_create too, and all the information you need will be ready before Devise sends the email.

Comment: @kolrie do you mind sharing how you are making a user to both a client and a seller.  You mentioned that a user could either be a seller or client or both. How do you get the user to be **both**. thanks